# This happens when i run makemigrations or migrate in django, How do i solve this error?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm trying to run makemigrations in my django project, but I get an unsolvable error.
My os is fedora 38 and im using vscode this only happens when I'm using postgress database(online).
but my code runs fine on sqlite3 database.

you can see the error below when I use makemigrations command:

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

And when I use migrate command this error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/.venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/.venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
.
.
.
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/.venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/stationary_store/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/stationary_store/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
.
.
.
  File "/home/arad/Django/store_project/.venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Help Please (0_0)

I have to say that I searched about this for hours and I tried so many things but to no avail.
Something they said was to manipulate `postgresql.conf` file and change the port number to 5432 but the content of this file is confusing.
you can see the contents below:

`d /run/postgresql 0755 postgres postgres -`

Oh and I'm not sure if this is the mentiond file.
Plus: I'm sure that my psycopg2-binary package is installed properly. and the wierd thing is that I've been getting this error lately(used postgresql last wee and it was working well but not any more.)

Comment: Either your local database server is not running, or if you are using a remote server, it is not configured properly in the [django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes).

Comment: @KlausD. but i'm sure that it is properly configured. plus my database is remote

Comment: Then I'm sure that exact exception wouldn't pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

first i ran `service postgresql status` on linux terminal. it said that the postgresql was deactivated.

then i ran `service postgresql start` and it solved my problem.